# my function doesn't return a list matlab

Tags: matlab

the following function should retun to me a list a files 
but it returns only the latest file

How could I get all files ?
Thanks,

```
function myResults = getFiles(opt ,nb)

            if ~isfield(opt, 'linux')
                opt.linux= false;
            end

            if opt.linux

                for ii=1:nb
                    myResults = {fullfile(opt.folder,['file',num2str(ii)])};
                end
            end   

        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overwriting `myResults` in each iteration. You probably want something like:

```
myResults(ii) = {fullfile(opt.folder,['file',num2str(ii)])};
```

Comment: Perhaps just `myResults(ii)`, as the result is a cell already. If you apply this, you will want to make the loop like this: `for ii = nb:-1:1`. This way Matlab will immediately know how big your variable is going to be and you can prevent inefficiencies/mlint warnings.

Comment: @am304: this will return 1x2 cell , and not the list of results

Comment: @Dennis, what does it mean nb:-1:1

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks, I started as `myResults(ii)` but then for whatever reason, I changed it to `myResults{ii}`. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @lola Instead of starting at 1 and going up 1 each time (by writing `1:5` or `1:1:5` for example) this way you do the loop backwards, like in `5:-1:1`. The advantage is that as soon as you write this fifth entry, first step of the loop, matlab will already reserve memory for the first four and can process those more efficiently. You can evaluate these fragments easily in the command window.